# why sometimes I get the results but sometimes not even though I run the same code?

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the review data for some hotels form trip advisor website. First, I try to scrape the review ID for the 1st review for a certain hotel. I ran my code and could get it. But the weird thing is that sometimes I get an error, index out of range, even though I run the same code (didn't change any line of my code). I'm not an expert of web scraping but my guess was that my code ran before I parsed the page. So I included time.sleep(n) in the middle of my code but still the same issue occurs. Does anyone know why it happens? Below is my code.

```
import urllib
import time
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page=urlopen("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g60878-d13428699-Reviews-Staybridge_Suites_Seattle_Downtown_Lake_Union-Seattle_Washington.html")
soup=BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")    
time.sleep(5)

listing=soup.find_all("div", class_="review-container")
review_id=listing[0]["data-reviewid"]
print (review_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a method that first goes with bs4 then tries regex. In a series of test runs that worked for me.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, re

page= requests.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g60878-d13428699-Reviews-Staybridge_Suites_Seattle_Downtown_Lake_Union-Seattle_Washington.html")
p = re.compile(r'id="review_(\d+)')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
ids = [i['data-reviewid'] for i in soup.select('[data-reviewid][class^=hotels-review-list-parts-SingleReview]')]
if not ids:
    ids = p.findall(page.text)
print ids
```